# Probability of choosing the right coin given the number of tosses

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to solve the following problem

> There are two indistinguishable coins, one of them is balanced and the other one is biased in a way that the probability of getting heads after a toss is twice the probability of getting tails after a toss.
> We choose one of them and toss it repeatedly. Find the probability of having chosen the balanced coin if
> i) The coin was tossed $15$ times and $5$ of them were heads.
> ii) We needed $15$ tosses to get $5$ heads.

Here is my attempt:
i) Let $B$ be the event of choosing the balanced coin and let $D$ be the event of choosing the coin with "probability of heads=double of probability of tails". Consider the random variable $X$ counting the number of heads obtained.
We have$$\mathbb{P}(X=5\mid B)=\binom{15}{5}\left (\frac{1}{2}\right )^5\left (\frac{1}{2}\right )^{15-5}=\frac{3003}{2^{15}}$$because if $B$ was chosen then $X\sim \operatorname{Bin}\left (15,\frac{1}{2}\right )$ and$$\mathbb{P}(X=5\mid D)=\binom{15}{5}\left (\frac{2}{3}\right )^5\left (\frac{1}{3}\right )^{15-5}=\frac{96096}{3^{15}}$$because if $D$ was chosen then $X\sim \operatorname{Bin}\left (15,\frac{2}{3}\right )$. We also have $\mathbb{P}(B)=\mathbb{P}(D)=\frac{1}{2}$ because the coins are indistinguishable. Hence using Bayes' Theorem we find$$\mathbb{P}(B\mid X=5)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X=5\mid B)\cdot \mathbb{P}(B)}{\mathbb{P}(X=5\mid B)\cdot \mathbb{P}(B)+\mathbb{P}(X=5\mid D)\cdot \mathbb{P}(D)}=\frac{\frac{3003}{2^{15}}}{\frac{96096}{3^{15}}}\approx 0.93$$as the desired probability.
ii) Let $B$ be the event of choosing the balanced coin and let $D$ be the event of choosing the coin with "probability of heads=double of probability of tails". Consider the random variable $X$ counting the number of tosses needed to obtain $5$ heads.
We have$$\mathbb{P}(X=15\mid B)=\dbinom{15-1}{5-1}\left (\dfrac{1}{2}\right )^5\left (\dfrac{1}{2}\right )^{15-5}=\dbinom{14}{4}\dfrac{1}{2^{15}}$$because if $B$ was chosen then $X\sim \operatorname{Pa}\left (\frac{1}{2},5\right )$ and$$\mathbb{P}(X=15\mid D)=\dbinom{15-1}{5-1}\left (\dfrac{2}{3}\right )^5\left (\dfrac{1}{3}\right )^{15-5}=\dbinom{14}{4}\dfrac{2^5}{3^{15}}$$because if $D$ was chosen then $X\sim \operatorname{Pa}\left (\frac{1}{3},5\right )$. Then similar computations give the same answer as the first item.

I would like to know if my solution is correct.

Comment: In the fraction before $\approx0.93$ you're missing the other term in the denominator.

Comment: You are right, it's a typo, but I think that the numerical answer is still correct, right? Doing all the computations I'm getting the probability as $\frac{3^{15}}{2^{20}+3^{15}}\approx 0.93$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between scenarios (i) and (ii).  It seems that in each case you tossed the coin $15$ times, resulting in $5$ heads.

Comment: @RobertShore: In the second scenario, we *needed* $15$ tosses, meaning that we didn't have $5$ heads yet after $14$ tosses; so the $15$th toss is known to be heads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution looks right to me. You get the same result in both parts because the dependence of the probabilities on the data is the same; the overall factor of $\frac13$ that comes from the additional constraint that the last toss resulted in heads is the same for the two coins and cancels out.